# "sending the device plummeting to the ground"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I am having problem in understanding this sentence, in particular this part "sending the device plummeting to the ground". Does "sending the device plummeting to the ground" modifying "its territory"? Are "sending" and "plummeting" both gerunds here?

> After this red-tailed hawk spots the unwanted guest, it goes on the
> offensive by swooping down to mark its territory, **sending the device
> plummeting to the ground**.

Comment: They are not gerunds. They are acting verbs.

Comment: The action of swooping sends the device plummeting (falling swiftly) to the ground.